# Battery Drains Way Too Quickly. What's Going On?

Tags: battery, battery-life, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I know there are many forums and posts already discussing battery issues, but I am posting here because I would like constructive and detailed feedback.

I have a S7 Edge running Nougat 7.1 not rooted, and a couple months ago, the battery used to drain by 5-10% overnight. Now, it drains by about 20-30%. I have tried different things to try to pin down the issue and/or alleviate it, but none seems to have worked.

*Note* that I have used the *pm uninstall* to get rid of some known bloatware and services.

I have tried 1) factory reset, 2) booting to Safe Mode, and 3) wiping the cache partition. The attached figures show the battery status at night and then the morning, and the captions indicate what action had been performed that night. I have pictures for all actions, but due to my reputation I can only post 2. Basically, the trend is that *Android OS* and *Android System* seem to always be in the range of 5-12% battery usage by the morning.

After all these methods, I really don't know what can be going on. Another interesting observation is that I lose more battery overnight, than during the day if my phone is just sitting in idle mode. Any constructive help/advice would be appreciated.

**Update:** Usually, the battery plot needs to stabilize overnight, indicating the phone is in deep sleep (or doze mode). I am thinking my phone is not able to reach doze and/or stay in that mode for a long time. Any ideas on that? I already have optimized all my applications.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried simple things like varying placement throughout your overnight residence? Is it consistently bad ? Is this one night? A straight line needs at least 2 points; more points yields better theories. Your notification bar seems busy; chances are your phone is too, _in a period of supposed downtime_.

Comment: yeah, this is one night. Other nights are similar too. I literally don't have much on my phone. Unless it's some weird unknown background process, I would know about it.

Comment: Seems like a wakelock issue. Have you gotten any new Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Ok, how do I monitor wakelock apps? I am not rooted and kinda don't plan to root. Ideas?